# Descomprimir un archivo .zip en PHP?

Tags: php, zip

Quisiera descomprimir un archivo que en que esta en un servidor usando php, alguien que sepa como hacerlo ?

Comment: Utilizas un framework o php puro??

Answer (score 1):

Es bastante sencillo, lo puedes hacer de esta forma:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
// Asumiendo que este script está en el mismo directorio del zip, de lo contrario
// puedes darle la ruta absoluta del archivo 
$res = $zip->open('nombre_archivo.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
  $zip->extractTo('/ruta/donde/guardar/archivos/');
  $zip->close();
  // Archivo descomprimido correctamente
} else {
   // Error descomprimiendo el archivo...
}
```

Puedes encontrar documentación más concreta y de manera oficial [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/ziparchive.extractto.php)